# Kotlin and Immutable Collections?

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin and it is looking likely I may want to use it as my primary language within the next year. However, I keep getting conflicting research that Kotlin does or does not have immutable collections and I'm trying to figure out if I need to use Google Guava.

Can someone please give me some guidance on this? Does it by default use Immutable collections? What operators return mutable or immutable collections? If not, are there plans to implement them?

Comment: There is a lightweight way to protect Kotlin collections as immutable rather than only as read-only, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38002121/3679676

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Kotlin's [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-list/index.html) from the standard library is readonly:

```
interface List<out E> : Collection<E> (source)
```

> A generic ordered collection of elements. Methods in this interface
> support only read-only access to the list; read/write access is
> supported through the MutableList interface.
>
> **Parameters**
> E - the type of elements contained in the list.

As mentioned, there is also the [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-mutable-list/index.html)

```
interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E> (source)
```

> A generic ordered collection of elements that supports adding and
> removing elements.
>
> **Parameters**
> E - the type of elements contained in the list.

Due to this, Kotlin enforces readonly behaviour through its interfaces, instead of throwing Exceptions on runtime like default Java implementations do.

Likewise, there is a `MutableCollection`, `MutableIterable`, `MutableIterator`, `MutableListIterator`, `MutableMap`, and `MutableSet`, see the [stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/index.html) documentation.

Comment: Interesting approach although it makes sense to ensure interoperability. I may stick with Guava collections because (the last time I checked) the performance is much better.

Comment: Kotlin collections are readonly, not immutable @nhaarman.  I suggested an edit to your answer.

Comment: Note that if you create a list using arrayListOf() the list returned is an ArrayList, which is mutable. If you want an immutable list you must use listOf() instead.

Answer (score 32):

It is confusing but there are three, not two types of immutability:

1. Mutable   - you are supposed to change the collection (Kotlin's `MutableList`)
2. Readonly - you are NOT supposed to change it (Kotlin's `List`) but something may (cast to Mutable, or change from Java)
3. Immutable - no one can change it (Guavas's immutable collections)

So in case (2) `List` is just an interface that does not have mutating methods, but you can change the instance if you cast it to `MutableList`.

With Guava (case (3)) you are safe from anybody to change the collection, even with a cast or from another thread.

Kotlin chose to be readonly in order to use Java collections directly, so there is no overhead or conversion in using Java collections..

Comment: Kotlin `List` is readonly, not immutable.  Other callers (Java for example) may change the list.  Kotlin callers might cast the list and change it.  There is no immutable protection.

Answer (score 18):

As you see in other answers, Kotlin has readonly interfaces to mutable collections that let you view a collection through a readonly lens.  But the collection can be bypassed via casting or manipulated from Java.  But in cooperative Kotlin code that is fine, most uses do not need truly immutable collections and if your team avoids casts to the mutable form of the collection then maybe you don't need fully immutable collections.

The Kotlin collections allow both copy-on-change mutations, as well as lazy mutations.  So to answer part of your questions, things like `filter`, `map`, `flatmap`, operators `+` `-` all create copies when used against non lazy collections.  When used on a `Sequence` they modify the values as the collection as it is accessed and continue to be lazy (resulting in another `Sequence`).  Although for a `Sequence`, calling anything such as `toList`, `toSet`, `toMap` will result in the final copy being made.  By naming convention almost anything that starts with `to` is making a copy.

In other words, most operators return you the same type as you started with, and if that type is "readonly" then you will receive a copy.  If that type is lazy, then you will lazily apply the change until you demand the collection in its entirety.

Some people want them for other reasons, such as parallel processing.  In those cases, it might be best to look at really high performance collections designed just for those purposes.  And only use them in those cases, not in all general cases.

In the JVM world it is hard to avoid interop with libraries that want standard Java collections, and converting to/from these collections adds a lot of pain and overhead for libraries that do not support the common interfaces.  Kotlin gives a good mix of interop and lack of conversion, with readonly protection by contract.

So if you can't avoid wanting immutable collections, Kotlin easily works with anything from the JVM space:

- **Guava** (https://github.com/google/guava)
- **Dexx** a port of the Scala collections to Java (https://github.com/andrewoma/dexx) with Kotlin helpers (https://github.com/andrewoma/dexx/blob/master/kollection/README.md)
- **Eclipse Collections** (formerly GS-Collections) a really high performance, JDK compatible, top performer in parallel processing with immutable and mutable variations (home: https://www.eclipse.org/collections/ and Github: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections)
- **PCollections** (http://pcollections.org/)

Also, the Kotlin team is working on Immutable Collections natively for Kotlin, that effort can be seen here:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable

There are many other collection frameworks out there for all different needs and constraints, Google is your friend for finding them.  There is no reason the Kotlin team needs to reinvent them for its standard library.  You have a lot of options, and they specialize in different things such as performance, memory use, not-boxing, immutability, etc.  "Choice is Good"  ... therefore some others:  [HPCC](https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc), [HPCC-RT](https://github.com/vsonnier/hppcrt), [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/), [Koloboke](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Koloboke), [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) and more...

There are even efforts like Pure4J which since Kotlin supports Annotation processing now, maybe can have a port to Kotlin for similar ideals.

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin 1.0 will not have immutable collections in the standard library. It does, however, have read-only and mutable *interfaces*.  And nothing prevents you from using third party immutable collection libraries.

Methods in Kotlin's [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-list/index.html) interface "support only read-only access to the list" while methods in its [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-mutable-list/index.html) interface support "adding and removing elements". Both of these, however, are only **interfaces**.

Kotlin's `List` interface enforces read-only access at compile-time instead of deferring such checks to run-time like [`java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(java.util.List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) (which "returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list... [where] attempts to modify the returned list... result in an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)." **It does not enforce immutability.**

Consider the following Kotlin code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import kotlin.test.assertFailsWith

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val readOnlyList: List<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3)
    val mutableList: MutableList<Int> = readOnlyList as MutableList<Int>
    val immutableList: ImmutableList<Int> = ImmutableList.copyOf(readOnlyList)

    assertEquals(readOnlyList, mutableList)
    assertEquals(mutableList, immutableList)

    // readOnlyList.add(4) // Kotlin: Unresolved reference: add
    mutableList.add(4)
    assertFailsWith(UnsupportedOperationException::class) { immutableList.add(4) }

    assertEquals(readOnlyList, mutableList)
    assertEquals(mutableList, immutableList)
}
```

Notice how `readOnlyList` is a `List` and methods such as `add` cannot be resolved (and won't compile), `mutableList` can naturally be mutated, and `add` on `immutableList` (from Google Guava) can also be resolved at compile-time but throws an exception at run-time.

All of the above assertions pass with exception of the last one which results in `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Expected <[1, 2, 3, 4]>, actual <[1, 2, 3]>.` i.e. We successfully mutated a read-only `List`!

Note that using `listOf(...)` instead of `arrayListOf(...)` returns an effectively immutable list as you cannot cast it to any mutable list type. However, using the `List` interface for a variable does not prevent a `MutableList` from being assigned to it (`MutableList<E>` extends `List<E>`).

Finally, note that an interface in Kotlin (as well as in Java) cannot enforce immutability as it "cannot store state" (see [Interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html)). As such, if you want an immutable collection you need to use something like those provided by Google Guava.

---

See also [ImmutableCollectionsExplained · google/guava Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained)

Comment: Your answer will be true for Kotlin 1.0, immutable collections are not on the table for the 1.0 release.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:**  *This answer is here because the code is simple and open-source and you can use this idea to make your collections that you create immutable.  It is not intended only as an advertisement of the library.*

In [Klutter library](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter), are new Kotlin Immutable wrappers that use Kotlin delegation to wrap a existing Kotlin collection interface with a protective layer without any performance hit.  There is then no way to cast the collection, its iterator, or other collections it might return into something that could be modified.  They become in effect Immutable.

> Klutter `1.20.0` released which adds immutable protectors for existing collections, based on a [SO answer by @miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37936456/3679676) provides a light-weight delegate around collections that prevents any avenue of modification including casting to a mutable type then modifying.  And Klutter goes a step further by protecting sub collections such as iterator, listIterator, entrySet, etc.  All of those doors are closed and using Kotlin delegation for most methods you take no hit in performance.    Simply call `myCollection.asReadonly()` (*protect*) or `myCollection.toImmutable()` (*copy then protect*) and the result is the same interface but protected.

Here is an example from the code showing how simply the technique is, by basically delegating the interface to the actual class while overriding mutation methods and any sub-collections returned are wrapped on the fly.

```
/**
 * Wraps a List with a lightweight delegating class that prevents casting back to mutable type
 */
open class ReadOnlyList <T>(protected val delegate: List<T>) : List<T> by delegate, ReadOnly, Serializable {
    companion object {
        @JvmField val serialVersionUID = 1L
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<T> {
        return delegate.iterator().asReadOnly()
    }

    override fun listIterator(): ListIterator<T> {
        return delegate.listIterator().asReadOnly()
    }

    override fun listIterator(index: Int): ListIterator<T> {
        return delegate.listIterator(index).asReadOnly()
    }

    override fun subList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int): List<T> {
        return delegate.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).asReadOnly()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "ReadOnly: ${super.toString()}"
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return delegate.equals(other)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return delegate.hashCode()
    }
}
```

Along with helper extension functions to make it easy to access:

```
/**
 * Wraps the List with a lightweight delegating class that prevents casting back to mutable type,
 * specializing for the case of the RandomAccess marker interface being retained if it was there originally
 */
fun <T> List<T>.asReadOnly(): List<T> {
    return this.whenNotAlreadyReadOnly {
        when (it) {
            is RandomAccess -> ReadOnlyRandomAccessList(it)
            else -> ReadOnlyList(it)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Copies the List and then wraps with a lightweight delegating class that prevents casting back to mutable type,
 * specializing for the case of the RandomAccess marker interface being retained if it was there originally
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> List<T>.toImmutable(): List<T> {
    val copy = when (this) {
        is RandomAccess -> ArrayList<T>(this)
        else -> this.toList()
    }
    return when (copy) {
        is RandomAccess ->  ReadOnlyRandomAccessList(copy)
        else -> ReadOnlyList(copy)
    }
}
```

You can see the idea and extrapolate to create the missing classes from this code which repeats the patterns for other referenced types.  Or view the full code here:

> https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/master/core-jdk6/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/core/common/Immutable.kt

And with tests showing some of the tricks that allowed modifications before, but now do not, along with the blocked casts and calls using these wrappers.

> https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/master/core-jdk6/src/test/kotlin/uy/klutter/core/collections/TestImmutable.kt

Answer (score 1):

Now we have https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable.

```kotlin
fun Iterable<T>.toImmutableList(): ImmutableList<T>
fun Iterable<T>.toImmutableSet(): ImmutableSet<T>
```

```kotlin
fun Iterable<T>.toPersistentList(): PersistentList<T>
fun Iterable<T>.toPersistentSet(): PersistentSet<T>
```