# Kotlin: What features of Java 8 are not yet supported?

Tags: java, java-8, compatibility, kotlin

Is there an up-to-date overview of Java 8 features, which are not yet supported in Kotlin?

---

For example, calling a default method like [Map#putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) fails to compile (unsupported reference error):

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x : Map<Int, Int> = HashMap<Int, Int>()
    x.putIfAbsent(1, 2)
}
```

If the default method is overridden, it works:

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x : HashMap<Int, Int> = HashMap<Int, Int>()
    x.putIfAbsent(1, 2)
}
```

That is what I found out by experiments, but for deciding whether migrating from a Java 8 code basis to Kotlin is already possible, a systematic overview would be valuable.

---

**Update:** The code in my example was created by the "Java to Kotlin" converter. As user2235698 pointed out, `Map<Int, Int>` is a immutable Kotlin map. Still, the example fails to compile when I change it to a `java.util.Map` map. My claim that it has to do something with default methods, however, is misleading.

As it is beyond the scope of this question, I opened a follow-up question, here: [Does java.util.HashMap not implement java.util.Map in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34255329/783510)

Comment: See the subtasks of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4778

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, your link is very good. I think I'll convert it to a community answer.

Comment: This question will always be out of date, the community wiki answer below (and the comment above) are the best places to track this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Known Java 8 interoperability issues are tracked as subtasks of [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4778)

Answer (score 3):

`Map` is **immutable** and `HashMap` is **mutable** in Kotlin, that's why you can't put key-value pair in the first case.

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732403/2235698)

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that Map is not java.util.Map. However, if I change my example to java.util.Map, it still fails to compile. I posted it as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34255329/783510