# Does java.util.HashMap not implement java.util.Map in Kotlin?

Tags: java, inheritance, language-lawyer, kotlin

I have trouble understanding why a Java `HashMap` is incompatible with a Java `Map` in Kotlin:

```
val map : java.util.Map<Int, Int> = java.util.HashMap<Int, Int>()
                                    // ERROR: Type mismatch
```

**Is this a bug or is it intentionally enforced to be an error in Kotlin?**

---

Here is a second example with the Java to Kotlin compiler. Take a look at this Java example file:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Map<Integer, Integer> map = new java.util.HashMap<>();
        insertValue(map);
    }

    private static void insertValue(java.util.Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        map.putIfAbsent(0, 1);
    }
}
```

Running "Convert Java to Kotlin" results in this file:

```
object Test {
    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val map = java.util.HashMap<Int, Int>()
        insertValue(map)
    }

    private fun insertValue(map: Map<Int, Int>) {
        map.putIfAbsent(0, 1)  // ERROR! Unresolved reference
    }
}
```

If I try to modify it to reflect more the original file, where `insertValue` expected a Java `java.util.Map`, I get another error:

```
object Test {
    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val map = java.util.HashMap<Int, Int>()
        insertValue(map)  // ERROR: Type mismatch
    }

    private fun insertValue(map: java.util.Map<Int, Int>) {
        map.putIfAbsent(0, 1)  // is now OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Kotlin, a `java.util.HashMap`, at compile time, does not implement `java.util.Map`, but implements `kotlin.collections.MutableMap` which extends the read-only `kotlin.collections.Map`.

This is because of Kotlin's [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types). See **Collections** in [Kotlin M3 is Out!](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2012/09/kotlin-m3-is-out/) for more details.

[`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/) does not define any `putIfAbsent`, but it has an extension function [`getOrPut`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/get-or-put.html).

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that `kotlin.MutableMap` does not exist at runtime?

Comment: Correct. That is why I wrote "at compile time" in my answer. Kotlin's [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) are available at compile-time but then mapped to different types at runtime. More details on platform types [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types).

Answer (score 3):

I created a bug report, primarily for the "Java to Kotlin" converter that generates invalid Kotlin code in my original example:

[KT-10400 Java to Kotlin converter: converting Java Code where a java.util.HashMap is accessed through the java.util.Map interface fails](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10400)

I also mentioned that `java.util.HashMap` does not implement `java.util.Map` but I leave it to the Kotlin developers to decide whether it is a bug or whether the compiler is right to reject it.

**UPDATE:** The bug is marked as solved (commit [5e231db6](https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin/commit/5e231db631865d28146649b0495c457ff5a9c2bf)).

Comment: I still experience the bug in kotlin 1.5.30

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is a bug. You can report it there
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

But still, `putIfAbsent` is a Java 8 feature, not yet supported in Kotlin (`MutableMap` interface missing this method).

Comment: I suspect the down votes were because of lack of references backing up this answer. e.g. This answer may have been considered more helpful by some if a link to an issue or relevant documentation about [calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) were provided which states/shows that Java Collections are not treated specially in Kotlin.

Comment: Personally I appreciate the answer but I wish it referenced a concrete issue or some documentation supporting that it might be a bug.

Comment: no need to down vote, the only supporting fact if that's a bug would be the illogicality of this behavior