# Kotlin generics mismatch in a class hierarchy

Tags: generics, kotlin

Why doesn't this work? It's working in Java though.

```
class MyList : java.util.LinkedList<String>()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x: java.util.List<String> = MyList()
}
```

I get

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is MyList but List<String> was expected
```

For the assignment line.

Link for online eval: http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/70dhmnocn8ueh73hg0o61mp01f/8ormftvrpbimfu0l3uf37galv

Comment: Similar question (although about `Map` instead of `List` but the same applies): http://stackoverflow.com/q/34255329/3255152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `val` declaration to:

```
val x: List<String> = MyList() // List<String>, not java.util.List<String>
```

What's likely the reason of this behavior is that Kotlin doesn't use the `java.util.List<E>` interface directly, instead, it is mapped to `kotlin.collections.List<E>` and `kotlin.collections.MutableList<E>`, which are imported by default, and there's even an IDE warning about `java.util.List<T>` usage.

Seemingly, `java.util.List<E>` is completely replaced with `kotlin.collections.List<E>` in the class hierarchy for `LinkedList<String>` during the type checking.

See the docs on Java collection interfaces mapping: [(link)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types)