# Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin

What is the difference between `List` and `Array` types?
It seems can make same operations with them (loops, filter expression, etc..), is there any difference in behavior or usage?

```
val names1 = listOf("Joe","Ben","Thomas")
val names2 = arrayOf("Joe","Ben","Thomas")

for (name in names1)
    println(name)
for (name in names2)
    println(name)
```

Answer (score 536, accepted):

[Arrays](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays) and lists (represented by [`List<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/) and its subtype [`MutableList<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html)) have many differences, here are the most significant ones:

- `Array<T>` is a class with known implementation: it's a sequential fixed-size memory region storing the items (and on JVM it is represented by [Java array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)).

  `List<T>` and `MutableList<T>` are interfaces which have different implementations: `ArrayList<T>`, `LinkedList<T>` etc. Memory representation and operations logic of lists are defined in concrete implementation, e.g. indexing in a `LinkedList<T>` goes through the links and takes O(n) time whereas `ArrayList<T>` stores its items in a dynamically allocated array.

  ```
  val list1: List<Int> = LinkedList<Int>()
  val list2: List<Int> = ArrayList<Int>()
  ```
- `Array<T>` is mutable (it can be changed through any reference to it), but `List<T>` doesn't have modifying methods (it is either [read-only view of `MutableList<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770493/kotlin-instantiate-immutable-list/34770659#34770659) or an [immutable list implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713274/java-immutable-collections)).

  ```
  val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
  a[0] = a[1] // OK

  val l = listOf(1, 2, 3)
  l[0] = l[1] // doesn't compile

  val m = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
  m[0] = m[1] // OK
  ```
- Arrays have fixed size and cannot expand or shrink retaining identity (you need to copy an array to resize it). As to the lists, `MutableList<T>` has `add` and `remove` functions, so that it can increase and reduce its size.

  ```
  val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
  println(a.size) // will always be 3 for this array

  val l = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
  l.add(4)
  println(l.size) // 4
  ```
- `Array<T>` is [invariant on `T`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) (`Array<Int>` is not `Array<Number>`), the same for `MutableList<T>`, but `List<T>` is covariant (`List<Int>` is `List<Number>`).

  ```
  val a: Array<Number> = Array<Int>(0) { 0 } // won't compile
  val l: List<Number> = listOf(1, 2, 3) // OK
  ```
- Arrays are optimized for primitives: there are separate `IntArray`, `DoubleArray`, `CharArray` etc. which are mapped to Java primitive arrays (`int[]`, `double[]`, `char[]`), not [boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) ones (`Array<Int>` is mapped to Java's `Integer[]`). Lists in general do not have implementations optimized for primitives, though some libraries (outside JDK) provide primitive-optimized lists.
- `List<T>` and `MutableList<T>` are [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) and have special behaviour in Java interoperability (Java's `List<T>` is seen from Kotlin as either `List<T>` or `MutableList<T>`). Arrays are also mapped, but they have [other rules](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-arrays) of Java interoperability.
- Certain array types are used in [annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotations) (primitive arrays, `Array<String>`, and arrays with `enum class` entries), and there's a special [array literal syntax for annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations). Lists and other collections cannot be used in annotations.
- As to the usage, good practice is to prefer using lists over arrays everywhere except for performance critical parts of your code, the reasoning is the same to [that for Java](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=39).

Answer (score 71):

The major difference from usage side is that [Arrays](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays) have a fixed size while [`(Mutable)List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) can adjust their size dynamically. Moreover `Array` is mutable whereas `List` is not.

Furthermore [`kotlin.collections.List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) is an interface implemented among others by `java.util.ArrayList`. It's also extended by `kotlin.collections.MutableList` to be used when a collection that allows for item modification is needed.

On the jvm level, `Array` is represented by [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html). `List` on the other hand is represented by [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) since there are no immutable collections equivalents available in Java.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced here. What's mutable in `Array`? Only it's elements - the same in the `List`. The size of `List` is also fixed.

Comment: @AndroidEx the following will compile `val intArray = arrayOf(1,2,3); intArray[0] = 2` while this will not `val intList = listOf(1,2,3); intList[0] = 2`. The `List` indeed has a fixed size but `MutableList` which extends it doesn't hence it is possible that a `val a:List<Int>` will report different `size` on subsequent calls.

Comment: Is it recommended to use `List` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you don't care about concrete implementation use `List` (probably 99% of the cases ). If you do care about implementation use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` or any other concrete implementation.

Answer (score 53):

In additional to the above, identity comparison is also different:

```
val l1 = listOf("a")
val l2 = listOf("a")
var x = (l1 == l2) // => true

val a1 = arrayOf("a")
val a2 = arrayOf("a")
var y = (a1 == a2) // => false
```

Comment: This answer helped me understand why data classes with arrays recommend that you implement the `equals` and `hashCode` functions, and do not when using lists.

Comment: reason for false op in-case of arrayOf()?

Comment: @UNREAL. When you use == with listOf, it checks if the content of the lists is the same. In the case of arrays, == checks for referential equality by default, meaning it checks if both sides refer to the same array instance.

So, in the first comparison (l1 == l2), the lists have the same content, resulting in true. In the second comparison (al == a2), even though the content is the same, the arrays are different instances, resulting in false.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation with a complex object**

```
// lets define a data class
data class Color(var name : String)
```

```
// lets define all 3 - array, list and mutableList for this Color object

val array = arrayOf(Color("Red"))
val list = listOf(Color("Red"))
val mutableList = mutableListOf(Color("Red"))
```

1. Methods on array

```
array.add(Color("Green"))  // Not Possible - cannot change size

array[0] = Color("Green")  // Possible - array object can be changed
array[0].name = "Green"   // Possible - object modification allowed by its class
```

2. Methods on list

```
list.add(Color("Green")) // Not Possible - cannot change size
list[0] = Color("Green") // Not Possible - list object cannot be changed

list[0].name = "Green"   // Possible - object modification allowed by its class
```

3. Methods on mutableList

```
mutableList.add(Color("Green"))   // Possible - can change size
mutableList[0] = Color("Green")   // Possible - can change object
mutableList[0].name = "Green"   // Possible - object modification allowed by its class
```

**Conclusions** :

1. arrays and list have fixed size, so you cannot add or remove elements
2. list cannot be modified, which means you cannot change the object it is holding
3. array can be modified, which means you can change the object it is holding
4. mutableList can do anything, change size or its objects

NOTE : This doesn't specify anything about the mutability of the object themselves. i.e. if the data class has some property as mutable (var), its property can be modified.