# How to convert a type-erased list to an array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin

A function `toArray` should convert type-erased list to `T` that is `Array<String>` now.

```
inline fun <reified T> toArray(list: List<*>): T {
    return list.toTypedArray() as T
}

toArray<Array<String>>(listOf("a", "b", "c")) // should be arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
```

However, `toArray` throws this error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Problem here, is that you actually trying cast `Object[]` to `String[]` in terms of Java, or `Array<Any>` to `Array<String>` in terms of Kotlin, but this is different objects.

So, this statement:

```
list.toTypedArray()
```

returns `Array<Any?>`, and then you trying to cast it to `Array<String>` and get `ClassCastException`.

#### How to fix?

I suggest pass type parameter itself, and cast `List`:

```
inline fun <reified T> toArray(list: List<*>): Array<T> {
    return (list as List<T>).toTypedArray()
}

toArray<String>(listOf("1", "2"))
```

Comment: Why not `inline fun <reified T> toArray(list: List<T>)`? It saves you from the unchecked cast, and `T` can also be inferred from the argument type.

Comment: Uhm, and this would be completely equivalent to `.toTypedArray()`... :)

Comment: I can't change the function's signature.

Answer (score 14):

To understand why this happens I recommend reading [Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36262305/3255152) and [Java Practices -> Prefer Collections over older classes](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=39).

In general I recommend using lists instead of arrays but if you want to convert a type-erased list to an array in Kotlin the easiest way to do so is first mapping to a typed list and then converting to a typed array:

```
list.map { it as String }.toTypedArray()
```

If you don't actually need an array but a typed list will do then you can simply map the type-erased list to a typed list:

```
list.map { it as String }
```

If you find yourself often converting a type-erased list to an array and performance matters then I recommend creating a map function optimized for doing this while avoiding an intermediary list:

```
inline fun <T, reified R> List<T>.mapToTypedArray(transform: (T) -> R): Array<R> {
    return when (this) {
        is RandomAccess -> Array(size) { index -> transform(this[index]) }
        else -> with(iterator()) { Array(size) { transform(next()) } }
    }
}
```

You can then efficiently convert a `List<*>` to a typed array:

```
list.mapToTypedArray { it as String }
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I was getting an invalid argument number exception when I was trying to do this:

```
val argumentTypeMirrors = mutableListOf<TypeMirror>()
... // add items to argumentTypeMirrors
val array = argumentTypeMirrors.toTypedArray()
```

And I ended up doing it this way:

```
val argumentTypeMirrors = mutableListOf<TypeMirror>()
... // add items to argumentTypeMirrors
val array = Array(argumentTypeMirrors.size) {
    argumentTypeMirrors[it]
}
```

Then I was able to destruct my `array` with `*array` for passing it as a `varargs` parameter.