# Kotlin: Cast ArrayList<String!> to Array<String>

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to split a string that is input by the user. My code looks similar to the following:

```
val aList = Array(5, {Array<String>(2){ " " }})
aList[0] = ArrayList(input.nextLine().split(" "))  // `split` returns a List
```

But this results in the following error:
`error: type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is ArrayList<String!> but Array<String> was expected`.

After some digging around I found that the `T!` operator means `T or T?`. How can I cast `ArrayList<String!>` to `Array<String>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ArrayList<T>` and `Array<T>` are [completely different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin), so, formally speaking, you cannot just make a cast.

You can, however, convert a `List<T>` to an `Array<T>` using [`.toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html):

```
aList[0] = input.nextLine().split(" ").toTypedArray()
```