# What is the difference between find and firstOrNull?

Tags: collections, kotlin

Given the following code extracted from [Kotlin Koans](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-koans/blob/resolutions/src/ii_collections/n15AllAnyAndOtherPredicates.kt#L36-L39):

```
fun Shop.findAnyCustomerFrom(city: City): Customer? {
    // Return a customer who lives in the given city, or null if there is none
    return customers.firstOrNull { it.isFrom(city) }
}
```

My own solution used `customers.find`. Both work in the koan scenario.

The documentation for [`firstOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) and [`find`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html) seem to be very similar.

What is the difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In this thread from 2014, Kotlin community members and JetBrains staff discuss the merits of the different methods `find` and `firstOrNull`:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5185

While not an official statement, JetBrains' employee Ilya Ryzhenkov describes it as:

> I think we can undeprecate `find` and make it an alias to `firstOrNull`. Much like `indexOf` has well-known semantics, `find` is also widely recognised as "find first item matching predicate or return null if nothing is found". People who like precise meaning can use `firstOrNull`, `singleOrNull` to express the intent.

In other words:

- `find(predicate)` and `firstOrNull(predicate)` are identical in behaviour and `find` can be considered alias of `firstOrNull`
- `find` is kept around as an alias because it's more intuitive and discoverable for programmers not already familiar with these Linq-style - or *functional* - methods.

In actuality the definition of `Array<out T>.find` is not defined as an alias, but as a wrapper (though the optimizing compiler will inline it, effectively making it an alias):
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Arrays.kt#L657

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Array<out T>.find(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    return firstOrNull(predicate)
}
```

Ditto for `Sequence<T>.find`:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Sequences.kt#L74

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Sequence<T>.find(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    return firstOrNull(predicate)
}
```

(I'm not a Kotlin user myself, but I'm surprised that these methods are implemented as compile-time generated code manually defined for each collection type instead of as a single JVM generic method - is there some reason for this?)

Comment: Arrays are optimized for primitives in Kotlin. Refers to [@hotkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263748/8343333).