# How to filter list of objects by the value of the one field in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have got list of objects

```
listOf(User("John",32), User("Katy",15), User("Sam",43))
```

How can write a function which returns me the User object if in parameter I pass a name. For example `getUser("John")` and it suppose to return me User("John",32)

Comment: See this question and its Kotlin doc links for helpful examples: [What is the difference between find and firstOrNull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520267/what-is-the-difference-between-find-and-firstornull)

Comment: In practice, if you were doing this more than once or twice you wouldn't search a list every time — much more efficient to convert it to a map, keyed on name, so you could look up users directly. You can create such a map directly from your list, by calling e.g. `associateBy{ it.name }`.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is also using `firstOrNull`:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(User("John",32), User("Katy",15), User("Sam",43))

list.firstOrNull { it.name == "John" }
```

Comment: I don't need first. It can stay on any place. What if I search for Sam? Will that work?

Comment: It returns the “first” one that matches the condition.