# Kotlin assumes value to be not null

Tags: kotlin

I have the below code to pick the first item from the list where the item's lastname field value should not be `UNKNOWN` or `MISSING`.

```
val userLastName = someList
      .first { it.lastName != "UNKNOWN" && it.lastName != "MISSING" }
      .lastName
```

Now Intellij says that the field userLastName can never be null. Why?

If the list has all objects whose `lastName` field value is either `UNKNOWN` or `MISSING` then the `userLastName` variable will be null right?

I tried to change the code to use null safe operator:

```
val userLastName = someList
          .first { it.lastName != "UNKNOWN" && it.lastName != "MISSING" }
          ?.lastName
```

But I get the below warning:

```
Safe call on a non-null receiver will have nullable type in future releases
```

Comment: .first() gives `java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate` incase the output is empty so it will not be null. The output of .filter() can be empty though but not for .first(). The `?.` is only for list that can contain null values and not for empty list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.first` function requires that at least one element matches the predicate. It throws an exception if no matching element is found.

If you want to instead return `null` when no elements match, you can use `.find` instead of `.first`.

Comment: Or `firstOrNull` (https://stackoverflow.com/q/45520267/6395627)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html

Comment: Hi, if I write code as `val someClassInstance = list.firstOrNull() as someClass` then Kotlin does not force me to cast the result to `someClass?` even though firstOrNull() output can be null. Why?

Comment: `as` is known as the ["unsafe" cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator) in Kotlin because it lets you attempt casts which may not succeed. It will throw an exception if the cast isn't possible. `x as SomeType` is similar to `x!!` in that it fails with an exception if `x` is `null`.