# How to convert String array to Int array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, type-conversion

Kotlin has many shorthands and interesting features. So, I wonder if there is some fast and short way of converting array of string to array of integers. Similar to this code in Python:

```
results = [int(i) for i in results]
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use [`.map { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) with [`.toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html) or [`.toIntOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html):

```
val result = strings.map { it.toInt() }
```

Only the result is not an array but a list. It is preferable to use lists over arrays in non-performance-critical code, see [the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin).

If you need an array, add [`.toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) or [`.toIntArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-int-array.html).

Answer (score 4):

I'd use something simple like

```
val strings = arrayOf("1", "2", "3")
val ints = ints.map { it.toInt() }.toTypedArray()
```

Alternatively, if you're into extensions:

```
fun Array<String>.asInts() = this.map { it.toInt() }.toTypedArray()

strings.asInts()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to convert a `List` structure that implements `RandomAccess` (like `ArrayList`, or `Array`), you can use this version for better performance:

```
IntArray(strings.size) { strings[it].toInt() }
```

This version is compiled to a basic for loop and `int[]`:

```
int size = strings.size();
int[] result = new int[size];
int index = 0;

for(int newLength = result.length; index < newLength; ++index) {
    String numberRaw = strings.get(index);
    int parsedNumber = Integer.parseInt(numberRaw);
    result[index] = parsedNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Array.map` as other answers suggest, you get back a `List`, not an `Array`. If you want to map an array `strings` to another array `results`, you can do it directly like this:

```
val results = Array(strings.size) { strings[it].toInt() }
```

This is more efficient than first mapping to a `List` and then copying the elements over to an `Array` by calling `.toTypedArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the input like this `""` (empty string)

It would be better to do the filtering first. And it is true the return value is list but not array.

If you need an array, add [`.toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) or [`.toIntArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html).

```
    fun stringToIntList(data: String): List<Int> =
            data.split(",").filter { it.toIntOrNull() != null }
                    .map { it.toInt() }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]".removeSurrounding("[","]").replace(" ","").split(",").map { it.toInt() }
```

Comment: The "[" and "," handling code is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @AndrewRegan would you care to give full reasons, why?

Comment: @RowlandMtetezi, because it is distracting, and question does not contain it.

Answer (score 0):

Found following simplest

```
strings.chars().toArray()
```