# Kotlin String to Int array

Tags: arrays, string, int, kotlin

I´m looking for the most efficient way to convert an String like

```
"[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

to an array of Int `[1,2,3,4,5]` in Kotlin

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823162/how-to-convert-string-array-to-int-array-in-kotlin

Comment: in the JavaScript version `JSON.parse<Array<Int>>("[1,2,3,4,5]")`

Comment: Hi Julian, the question you suggest as duplicated refers to an array of Strings, and clearly is not the case here. This question is about only one String, containing and array of Int

Comment: For better understanding, here is a question asking for the same case, but in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646392/convert-string-to-int-array-in-java

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25839398/3195526) to the above question is pretty easy to translate to idionmatic Kotlin. Or use klaxon or JSONObject, for an answer like @Slai's

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fortunately I've been able to make it work, so I'll leave it here for future reference

```
val result = "[1,2,3,4,5]".removeSurrounding("[", "]").split(",").map { it.toInt() }
```

Many thanks to all!

Comment: Competitive programming? Either way, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When user convert list to string and again need that string to list.
 Due to space between integer app crashes with NumberFormatException for that just remove unnecessary space.

```
val result = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]".removeSurrounding("[","]").replace(" ","").split(",").map { it.toInt() }
```

Comment: simply call it.trim().toInt() to remove empty spaces

Comment: @RichardMuvirimi Can one not specify 2 characters in split? As in `List.split(",\ ")`

Comment: @NateT use regex https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with toCharArray() cutting first and last ( '[' and ']' )

```
inline fun String.toCharArray(
    destination: CharArray, 
    destinationOffset: Int = 0, 
    startIndex: Int = 1, 
    endIndex: Int = length -1
): CharArray (source)
```

You can then manually copy converted values from char to int in a new array

[See more in the kotlin webpage](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-char-array.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also another way to achieve this:

```
"[1,2,3,4,5]".replace(Regex("""[\[,\]]"""), "").map { it - '0' }
```