# How do I convert an array of Strings to an Array of Int in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I am looking to convert an `List<String>` to an `List<Int>` in Kotlin.

```
val stringArray = "1 2 3 4 5 6".split(" ")
val intArray = MutableList<Int>(0, {0})
for (item in stringArray) {
    intArray.add(item.toInt())
}
```

The above will do it, but it feels as if there is a better way of doing this (possible with lambdas and streams?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String array to Int array in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823162/how-to-convert-string-array-to-int-array-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your input really has delimiters, you can `split` as already suggested. Afterwards `map` is what you need. This will do the trick:

```
val numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 6"
val result = numbers.split(" ").map(String::toInt)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val intArray = stringArray.map(String::toInt)
```

or with lambda

```
val intArray = stringArray.map { it.toInt() }
```

Comment: Great answers. But can you expand how they are different?

Comment: They do the same with your array, it's just the type of parameter which defers: in the first example a *method reference*, in the second a *lambda* is passed to `map`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map { ... }` with .toInt() or `.toIntOrNull()`:

```
 val result = strings.map { it.toInt() }
```

Only the result is not an array but a list. It is preferable to use lists over arrays in non-performance-critical code, see the differences.

If you need an array, add `.toTypedArray()` or `.toIntArray()`.