# Using Kotlin's MutableList or ArrayList where lists are needed in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, mutablelist

I am trying to learn the "Kotlin native way" to do things in Android, while being an expert in neither Kotlin, Java, nor Android development.  Specifically, **when to use `ArrayList` versus `MutableList`**.

It seems to me that [`MutableList` should be chosen whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263748/534238). Yet, if I look at Android examples, they seem to always choose the `ArrayList` (as far as I've found so far).

Below is a snippet of a working example that uses `ArrayList` and extends Java's `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

```
class PersonListAdapter(private val list: ArrayList<Person>,
                        private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
```

### Question 1)

Could I simply write the above code as follows (note `MutableList<>` instead of `ArrayList<>`), even though I am borrowing from Android's Java code?

```
class PersonListAdapter(private val list: MutableList<Person>,
                        private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
```

### Question 2)

Is it really better to always use `MutableList` over `ArrayList`? What are the main reasons? Some of that link I provide above goes over my head, but it seems to me that `MutableList` is a looser implementation that is more capable of changing and improving in the future. Is that right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is:

- if you use `ArrayList()` you are explicitly saying "*I want this to be an `ArrayList` implementation of `MutableList` and never change to anything else*".
- If you use `mutableListOf()` it is like saying "*Give me the default `MutableList` implementation*".

Current default implementation of the `MutableList` (`mutableListOf()`) returns an `ArrayList`. If in the (unlikely) event of this ever changing in the future (if a new more efficient implementation gets designed) this could change to `...mutableListOf(): MutableList<T> = SomeNewMoreEfficientList()`.

In that case, wherever in your code you used `ArrayList()` this will stay `ArrayList`. Wherever you have used `mutableListOf()` this would change from `ArrayList` to the brilliantly named `SomeNewMoreEfficientList`.

Comment: When is it recommended to use `ArrayList` over `List`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you would use `ArrayList` explicitly If you wanted to ensure that your implementation would never change to anything else (stay `ArrayList` event if `mutableListOf()` changes in future to return something else). 
Note that, probably the only reason an implementation would change would be the advent of some new `SomeNewMoreEfficientList` to replace the `ArrayList`. From that perspective one would probably want the swap to happen. Unless you identify something specific from ArrayList your app depends on and you believe it is something which might change, then use `mutableListOf`

Comment: Yea, IMO `mutableListOf` is better overall than ArrayList

Answer (score 12):

ArrayList is an implementation of the MutableList interface in Kotlin:

```
class ArrayList<E> : MutableList<E>, RandomAccess
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html

That answer may indicate that MutableList should be chosen whenever possible, but ArrayList *is* a MutableList. So if you're already using ArrayList, there's really no reason to use MutableList instead, especially since you can't actually directly create an instance of it (MutableList is an interface, not a class).

In fact, if you look at the `mutableListOf()` Kotlin extension method:

```
public inline fun <T> mutableListOf(): MutableList<T> = ArrayList()
```

you can see that it just returns an ArrayList of the elements you supplied.

Comment: Yes, @TheWanderer, I saw that `mutableListOf` is really just `ArrayList` under the hood.  I somehow didn't notice that `MutableList` was just an interface.  So, this helps!  But why even have `mutableListOf` in this case?  I guess I still don't understand the philosophy; to me, it seems a bit like polluting a namespace: there are now two functions that do *precisely* the same thing. To me, it seems like bad programming to increase cognitive load like this with no benefit whatsoever, but I figured I must be wrong and I had to be missing something.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson it returns an instance of ArrayList, but under the MutableList type. I don't know any reason you'd want to use that, but it is different from `arrayListOf()`.

Comment: yes, that's right, of course.  I forgot about that.  So... trivially different, but indeed different.  :-)

Comment: Since `ArrayList is an implementation of the MutableList interface` I don't get the reason why when working with Moshi and Retrofit2 with RxJava you cannot use Obeservable<ArrayList<YourClass>> only MutableList, List and other types stated here https://github.com/square/moshi#built-in-type-adapters

Comment: Why when I go to the source code of ArrayList in Kotlin it does not show that it was derived from MutableList? It redirect me to TypeAliases.ktx with this line of code `@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias ArrayList<E> = java.util.ArrayList<E>`

Comment: @MihaeKheel I don't know how those libraries work internally, and interoperability can be complex, but Kotlin's ArrayList both implements MutableList and is a typealias for Java's ArrayList. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/