# Kotlin: Returning Array<E> from function with return type Array<I> if E is enum class that implements interface I

Tags: kotlin, enums, type-mismatch, generic-variance

Recently I ran into a problem where I had a function which had to return an Array of `I`s, in form of all values of enum `E`, with `E` implementing interface `I`, with every code that came to my mind compiler complained about type mismatch:

```
Error:(x, x) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<E> but Array<I> was expected
```

A minimal example:

```
    interface I {}
    enum class E: I {
        A, B, C;
    }
    fun getMoreInterfaces(): Array<I> {
        return E.values()
    }
```

This happens when trying to assign `E.values()` to variable of type `Array<I>`
I am positive that this should be possible since `E` implements `I`.

Another thing that I came up while testing is that it works just fine when used like this:

```
    interface I {}
    enum class E: I {
        A, B, C;
    }
    fun getMoreInterfaces(): Array<I> {
        return arrayOf(E.A, E.B, E.C)
    }
```

I did a lot of searching on this topic but with no luck (perhaps I chose the wrong way to describe it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java, `Array<T>` is invariant on `T`, so, for `E` that is a subtype of `I`, `Array<E>` and `Array<I>` are not subtypes of each other. See: [Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance).

Given that the `Array<T>` types also store the item type and cannot be subject to fully [unchecked casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unchecked-casts), your best way to solve this is to create a separate array.

You can do that by either creating an array manually and filling it with the items, like in your example (or by using the constructor [`Array(n) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html)), or use [`.toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) applied to the list representation of the array ([`.asList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-list.html)):

```
fun getMoreInterfaces(): Array<I> {
    return E.values().asList().toTypedArray()
}
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

But basically, you can just go with a `List<I>` if you are not in performance-critical code, which is more idiomatic for Kotlin than working with arrays, and also simpler.

See also: [Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

`Array` is an invariant generic type in Kotlin, so if you need to return an instance of `Array<I>`, you can't return `Array<E>` instead, even if `E` is a subtype of `I`.

But in case if you are only *consuming* values from the returned array, you can declare its type as `Array<out I>`. This type is a covariant projection of type `Array<I>` and it allows you to return both `Array<I>` and `Array<E>`.

```
interface I {}
enum class E: I {
    A, B, C
}
fun getMoreInterfaces(): Array<out I> {
    return E.values()
}
```