# Why is arrayOf() the same as mutableListOf() but limited?

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to understand what the point was when making `arrayOf()` the same as `mutableListOf()` but removing features such as `add()` and `remove()`?

Comment: Do you mean `mutableListOf()`?

Comment: Yes `mutableListOf()`, edited

Comment: It feels like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36262305/115145) is a duplicate of your question. Is there something specific that you are interested in that is not covered in that question and its answers?

Comment: That's a good explanation thanks. So mainly the only reason to use arrays are for performance enhancements (searching for objects in the array quicker)?. Also I couldn't seem to find the advantage of using a `List` over a `MutableList`?

Comment: In a lot of modern programming, we try to use immutable objects where possible. Kotlin emphasizes this (`val` versus `var`, `MutableList` versus `List`, etc.). Immutability has a lot of positive benefits (e.g., two threads can access the object simultaneously without conflict).

Comment: One important thing about the way Kotlin implements the `mutableListOf()` method is that it makes a new ArrayList. An ArrayList just wraps a normal `Object[]` and then uses the `Arrays.copyOf()` method to "extend" that array size when needed.

Comment: You may need to deal with methods taking `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same:

`arrayOf()` creates an [`Array`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html) and `mutableListOf()` an [`ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) under the hood.

Which one you choose depends on your application.

An array is a fixed size data structure. In order to add/remove values you need to create a copy of the old array with the new changes (which is expensive), but no matter you large the array, accessing an element has constant time complexity. You need to do that manually though.

The `ArrayList` on the other hand uses an array for internal representation as well, but provides you with a mutable interface. So, adding/removing an element will still causes the internal array to be copied, but this process is abstracted away from you.

**Conclusion:**

- If you need to initialize the list once and after hat only access it, you should use an `Array`.
- If you need to add/remove elements in very few instances and the majority is reading, you should use an `ArrayList`.
- If you need to constantly add/remove values, use a `LinkedList`.