# Kotlin - Array property in data class error

Tags: json, kotlin

I'm modelling some JSON - and using the following lines

```
data class Metadata(
        val id: String,
        val creators: Array<CreatorsModel>
)
```

along with:

```
data class CreatorsModel (
        val role: String,
        val name: String
)
```

However keep seeing the error: `Array property in data class error`.

Any ideas why this is?

FYI, the JSON looks like:

```
{
"id": "123",
"creators": [{
   "role": "Author",
    "name": "Marie"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: maybe you should try List instead of Array?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Kotlin you should aim to use `List` instead of `Array` where possible. `Array` has some JVM implications, and although the compiler will let you, the IDE may prompt you to override `equals` and `hashcode` manually. Using `List` will make things much simpler.

You can find out more about the difference here: [Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin/36263748)

Comment: what about `ByteArray`? I plan to use Entity with image field to save it for the Room

Comment: @user924 Your best bet is to wrap the `ByteArray` in a wrapper and use that wrapper in the data class. That will overcome this limitation.