# Access to out bound elements of an Array in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin

Most of the logic i use to work on arrays in JavaScript depends on me being able to play with indexes. I am making the transition to kotlin ,so i have encountered that some of the logic i use doesn't fit kotlin.

Something as simple as initializing an Array and then accessing an undefined index seems to be more complicated than i am used to .

I understand that there are multiple ways of adding to lists on kotlin and accessing arrays and stuff. But what i want to know is What options do i have to Make arrays with unfixed Size and then add elements to the array in an indiscriminated order.
I just took the udacity kotlin boot camp last week but i have been having issues when using indexes as i used in javascript.

```
// JavaScript Code
var W = Array();
W[0] = 1
//Kotlin 
var W = arrayOf()
W[0] =1
```

IndexOutofbounds Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, `Array`s have a fixed size, unlike `List`s which can grow and shrink as items are added or removed.

If you want to use a `List` (specifically, a `MutableList`), you could start with an empty one, and then append items to it as needed, e.g.:

```
val l = mutableListOf<Int>()
l += 1
```

Or you could use an `Array`, created with the appropriate size, e.g.:

```
val a = Array(10){ 0 }
a[0] = 1
```

However, that procedural idiom of first creating a structure and then iterating to fill it isn't needed as much in Kotlin, as there are often functional ways of creating the structure and initialising it in one go.

If you're creating a list from something you can iterate (e.g. a range, another list, an array, a String, or whatever), then you can use `map()`:

```
val newList = (0..9).map{ it * 2 + 1 }
```

Or you can specify (how to calculate) array values when you create it:

```
val a = Array(10){ it * 2 + 1 }
```

(There are many more sophisticated possibilities, too!)

That style is often easier to read and maintain, as it concentrates more on *what* you're trying to do than *how* you do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a String to a byte array, Kotlin Std Lib already includes an [extension fun for that](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html)

```
fun String.toByteArray(
    charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8
): ByteArray

// Example from Kotlin Docs
val charset = Charsets.UTF_8
val byteArray = "Hello".toByteArray(charset)
println(byteArray.contentToString()) // [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
println(byteArray.toString(charset)) // Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to you arrayOf(), you have to init.
try this,

```
val arr = arrayOf(1,2,3)
//arr[0] = 1
//arr[1] = 2
//arr[2] = 3
```

Also if an array element can have a null value or if the type of the element allows null values, then the arrayOfNulls <> () function must be used.

```
val arr1 = arrayOf(1,2,3)
val arr2 = arrayOfNulls<Int>(5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @S T The issue i have mostly is that i depend on the array letting me go out of bound, So that's my main interest. If i could really help me to translate my code (From JavaScript to Kotlin) in the most direct way possible. 
For Example:

function str2binb(str) {
    var bin = Array();
    var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
        bin[i >> 5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (24 - i % 32);
    return bin;
}
Going out of bound is embedded into the logic of the code, as something expected of javascrip.

Comment: function str2binb(str) {
        var bin = Array();
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
            bin[i >> 5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (24 - i % 32);
        return bin;
    }

Comment: I think you can just use the `arrayOfNulls` helper to pre-size your array to the correct size.

Comment: Note that an `Array` cannot be resized (unlike a `MutableList`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin