# Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter E in fun <E> <init>(): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<E>

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist

I declared a variable like this:

```
var G: Array<MutableList<Int>> = Array(0) { ArrayList() }
```

Kotlin gives me the following error:

```
Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter E in fun <E> <init>(): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<E> /* = java.util.ArrayList<E> */
Please specify it explicitly.
```

It means Kotlin can't infer the type for the ArrayList which should be `Int`. So I add `Int` explicitly for the ArrayList like following:

```
var G: Array<MutableList<Int>> = Array(0) { ArrayList<Int>() }
```

Kotlin says - **Remove explicit types arguments**

In this case, Kotlin is ambivalent about how to act.

So is it possible to write code without explicitly declaring the type of ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-collection-vs-java-util-collection/256),

> The way it works curretly is that whenver we encounter a collection in Kotlin, we load a Kotlin version of this class (e.g. kotlin.Collection) instead of a Java version (java.util.*). Using the type java.util.Collection leads to a warning from the Kotlin compiler, because Kotlin's type checker is designed to distinguish between read-only and mutable collections.

So you can try to use like this,

```
var G = arrayOf<MutableList<Int>>()
```

Moreover, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263748/1084174) are some a good stuff to know for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Kotlin says - Remove explicit types arguments

Kotlin doesn't (you can see there's no warning in https://pl.kotl.in/7v1h5Yobu). It's probably the IDEA plugin which does. If you look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT?q=Remove%20explicit%20types%20arguments, you can see there are quite a few false positives. It may be worth checking if yours is actually one of them and posting a new issue if it isn't.

```
var G = Array<MutableList<Int>>(0) { ArrayList() }
```

should work without warning from IDEA either.