# Sort array according values from another array

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, sorting

I have two arrays .First array (points) is arrayOf(22, 8, 17, 13, 20) and second is an empty array. How can I set the rating to second array, according points in the first array. E.g. largest value is 22, so first element in the second array will have value 1. Second the largest value in the first array is 20, so last element in the second array will have value 2. At the end second array will look next (1, 5, 3, 4, 2). What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```kotlin
fun rankArray(unranked: Array<Int>): Array<Int> {
    val sorted = unranked.sortedArrayDescending() //create a temp array sortest from greatest to least
    val final = ArrayList<Int>() //create a arraylist because it's expandable
    for(element in unranked) final.add(sorted.indexOf(element) + 1) //add to the list the ranking from greatest to least in the same order as the data originally was
    return final.toTypedArray() //return result as array not arraylist
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. It's very helped me! Best of the best answer)

Comment: Performance note: this runs in `Θ(n^2)` time (i.e. guaranteed much slower than sorting on large arrays) while [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75866721/3169238) runs in `O(n logn)` time (i.e. same asymptotic as just sorting)

Answer (score 3):

To make RandomLonlyDev's answer a bit more the Kotlin way:

```kotlin
val rankedArray = arrayOf(22, 8, 17, 13, 20)
    .mapIndexed { index, number -> Pair(index, number) } // [(0, 22), (1, 8), (2, 17), (3, 13), (4, 20)] 
    .sortedByDescending { it.second } // [(0, 22), (4, 20), (2, 17), (3, 13), (1, 8)] 
    .map { it.first + 1 } // [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
    .toTypedArray() // the map & sort functions return a list, so revert back to array
```

*Also, you probably want to switch to a list instead of using an array. Check out the [Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin) answer!*

Answer (score 2):

Create a class

```
class ValueAndIndex implements Comparable<ValueAndIndex> {
    final int value;
    final int index;

    ValueAndIndex(int value, int index) {
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override public int compareTo(ValueAndIndex other) {
        // compare on value;
        if (this.value > other.value) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.value < other.value) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

then paste this code

```
int[] intArray1 = {22, 8, 17, 13, 20};
        List<ValueAndIndex> secondaryList = new ArrayList<>(intArray1.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray1.length; ++i) {
            secondaryList.add(new ValueAndIndex(intArray1[i], i+1));
        }
        Collections.sort(secondaryList);
        int [] indexesInSortedOrder = new int[intArray1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < secondaryList.size(); ++i) {
            indexesInSortedOrder[i] = secondaryList.get(i).index;
        }
        Log.d("Array", Arrays.toString(indexesInSortedOrder));
```

output: [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]

Comment: They are using kotlin not java

Comment: @RandomLonelyDev, We can easily convert java code to kotlin by just copy and paste this code to .kt file which is easily converts the code. Happy coding...

Comment: in Intellij, probably yes.  providing an answer in kotlin will still be more beneficial for others who use different IDE's.

Comment: This may be helpful for others they are looking for native code...