# How to turn a Mutable Collection into an Immutable one

Tags: kotlin

I was writing a small piece of code in which I internally handle my data in a mutable map, which in turn has mutable lists.

I wanted to expose my data to the API user, but to avoid any unsafe publication of my data I wanted to expose it in immutable collections even when internally being handled by mutable ones.

```
class School {

    val roster: MutableMap<Int, MutableList<String>> = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<String>>()

    fun add(name: String, grade: Int): Unit {
        val students = roster.getOrPut(grade) { mutableListOf() }
        if (!students.contains(name)) {
            students.add(name)
        }
    }

    fun sort(): Map<Int, List<String>> {
        return db().mapValues { entry -> entry.value.sorted() }
                .toSortedMap()
    }

    fun grade(grade: Int) = db().getOrElse(grade, { listOf() })
    fun db(): Map<Int, List<String>> = roster //Uh oh!
}
```

I managed to expose only `Map` and `List` (which are immutable) in the public API of my class, but the instances I am actually exposing are *still* inherently mutable.

Which means an API user could simply cast my returned map as an ImmutableMap and gain access to the precious private data internal to my class, which was intended to be protected of this kind of access.

I couldn't find a copy constructor in the collection factory methods `mutableMapOf()` or `mutableListOf()` and so I was wondering what is the best and most efficient way to turn a mutable collection into an immutable one.

Any advice or recommendations?

Comment: An "immutable list" is also referred to an "unmodifiable list"; this may help when searching for implementations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently in Kotlin stdlib there are no implementations of `List<T>` (`Map<K,V>`) that **would not also implement** `MutableList<T>` (`MutableMap<K,V>`). However due to [Kotlin's delegation feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) the implementations become one liners:

```
class ImmutableList<T>(private val inner:List<T>) : List<T> by inner
class ImmutableMap<K, V>(private val inner: Map<K, V>) : Map<K, V> by inner
```

You can also enhance the creation of the immutable counterparts with extension methods:

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.toImmutableMap(): Map<K, V> {
    if (this is ImmutableMap<K, V>) {
        return this
    } else {
        return ImmutableMap(this)
    }
}

fun <T> List<T>.toImmutableList(): List<T> {
    if (this is ImmutableList<T>) {
        return this
    } else {
        return ImmutableList(this)
    }
}
```

The above prevents a caller from modifying the `List` (`Map`) by casting to a different class. However there are still reasons to create a copy of the original container to prevent subtle issues like [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

```
class ImmutableList<T> private constructor(private val inner: List<T>) : List<T> by inner {
    companion object {
        fun <T> create(inner: List<T>) = if (inner is ImmutableList<T>) {
                inner
            } else {
                ImmutableList(inner.toList())
            }
    }
}

class ImmutableMap<K, V> private constructor(private val inner: Map<K, V>) : Map<K, V> by inner {
    companion object {
        fun <K, V> create(inner: Map<K, V>) = if (inner is ImmutableMap<K, V>) {
            inner
        } else {
            ImmutableMap(hashMapOf(*inner.toList().toTypedArray()))
        }
    }
}

fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.toImmutableMap(): Map<K, V> = ImmutableMap.create(this)
fun <T> List<T>.toImmutableList(): List<T> = ImmutableList.create(this)
```

While the above is not hard to implement there are already implementations of immutable lists and maps in both [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) and [Eclipse-Collections](https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-collections).

Comment: A fuller version of this was added to Klutter blocking all related actions such as an `Iterator` recieved from a list, a `subList` from a list, a `entrySet` from a map and more.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38002121/3679676

Answer (score 28):

Use **Java `Collections`** to converts a **mutable** list to an **immutable** list:

Creating a mutable list:

```
val mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()
```

Converting into an immutable (or unmodifiable) list:

```
val immutableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(mutableList)
```

---

More details [as indicated by the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).

Comment: Time complexity of `Collections.unmodifiableList()` is O(1) as it simply wraps the list with an `UnmodifiableList`. `UnmodifiableList` class overrides all methods that mutate the list to return `UnsupportedOperationException`. [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) | [Source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L1285)

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770493/kotlin-instantiate-immutable-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727657/kotlin-and-immutable-collections), you'd need to write your own `List` implementation for that, or use an existing one (Guava's ImmutableList comes to mind, or [Eclipse Collections](https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-collections) as [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278836/andrew-white) suggested).

Kotlin enforces list (im)mutability by interface only. There are no `List` implementations that don't also implement `MutableList`.

Even the idiomatic `listOf(1,2,3)` ends up calling Kotlin's `ArraysUtilJVM.asList()` which calls Java's `Arrays.asList()` which returns a plain old Java `ArrayList`.

If you care more about protecting your own internal list, than about the immutability itself, you can of course copy the entire collection and return it as an `List`, just like Kotlin does:

```
return ArrayList(original)
```

Comment: Small correction, `Arrays.asList` returns a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` (not to be confused with `java.util.ArrayList`). This list is somewhat immutable in that you can't add or remove items, but you can replace items by index.

Answer (score 11):

Simply call `toMap()` on your `MutableMap`.

```kotlin
val myMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>("x" to "y").toMap()
```

Done.

The same also works for lists.

Comment: maybe this was correct at some point, but looking at the implementation this still results in a mutable map: `else -> toMutableMap()`

Comment: Kotlin seems to perform some magic, though, despite returning a map which is Mutable. It will happily cast it, but it throws an error trying to mutate it. You can see an example in this playground: https://pl.kotl.in/nwer4AExQ

Badly formatted code from playground below:

`val a = mutableMapOf(1 to 1)
val b: Map<Int, Int> = a.toMap()
val c = b.toMutableMap()
val d: MutableMap<Int, Int> = if (b is MutableMap<*,*>) b as MutableMap else mutableMapOf()
    
c[2] = 2
println("a = $a, b = $b, c = $c, d = $d")
d[4] = 4 // crashes
println("a = $a, b = $b, c = $c, d = $d")
`

Answer (score 3):

I know this a Kotlin specific question and @Malt is correct but I would like to add an alternative. In particular I find [Eclipse Collections](https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-collections), formally GS-Collections, as a better alternative to Guava for most cases and it supplements Kotlin's built in collections well.

Answer (score 2):

A classic solution is to copy your data, so that even if modified, the change would not affect the private class property:

```
class School {
    private val roster = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<String>>()

    fun db(): Map<Int, List<String>> = roster.mapValuestTo {it.value.toList}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert `MutableMap<String, Any>` strictly to `ImmutableMap<String, Any>`, this will not work

```
val iMap : ImmutableMap<String, Any> = mutMap.toMap() // error
```

I have found the only working way:

```
val iMap : ImmutableMap<String, Any> =  ImmutableMap.builder<String, Any>().putAll(mutMap).build()
```

Answer (score -2):

Use simple bellow codes to convert Mutable Collections into an Immutable one:

```
val mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()

val immutableList: List<String> = mutableList
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this -- The poster already said that they are doing that, but don't like that this exposes the internal structure if someone wanted to cast it. Calling `.toMap()` is a much better choice IMO.