# The relationship between shared Interface in Java and Kotlin (ex: List<>)

Tags: java, list, interface, kotlin

The question came up when I took a closer look at kotlin .map inline function. Here's its definition

```
public inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.map(transform: (T) -> R): List<R>{
return mapTo(ArrayList<R>(collectionSizeOrDefault(10)), transform)}
```

In the function definition, it should return a List, which is defined in Collection.kt. However, it is returning an ArrayList, which implements a List interface in Java (List.java)

What is the relationship between Java interface and Kotlin interface ? I imagine there would be more similar examples, maybe Set, or Map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the JVM platform, the Kotlin interface `kotlin.collections.List` is **mapped** to Java interface `java.util.List`, and so is `kotlin.collections.MutableList`.

It means that the usages of these Kotlin interfaces are compiled to usages of the Java `List` interface in the bytecode. On the other hand, the Java `List` interface usages in the signatures read from the libraries are seen as `kotlin.collections.(Mutable)List`.

There are more mapped types: [see the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types).

This allows for calling Kotlin from Java and vice versa in a seamless way while still representing the Java types as `kotlin.*` classes in Kotlin, which, for example, saves us from primitives and arrays not being classes, and introduces [immutability through interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34770659/2196460).

Comment: Thank you, the answer is comprehensive, correct and with references.