# Difference between ArrayList<String>() and mutableListOf<String>() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
private val repositories = mutableListOf<String>()

private val repositories = ArrayList<String>()
```

Both are mutable list, then what is the point of two keywords `mutableListOf` or `ArrayList`?

or is there any major difference?

Comment: Neither `mutableListOf` nor `ArrayList` are keywords in Kotlin

Answer (score 215, accepted):

The only difference between the two is communicating your intent.

When you write `val a = mutableListOf()`, you're saying "I want a mutable list, and I don't particularly care about the implementation". When you write, instead, `val a = ArrayList()`, you're saying "I specifically want an `ArrayList`".

In practice, in the current implementation of Kotlin compiling to the JVM, calling `mutableListOf` will produce an `ArrayList`, and there's no difference in behaviour: once the list is built, everything will behave the same.

Now, let's say that a future version of Kotlin changes `mutableListOf` to return a different type of list.

Likelier than not, the Kotlin team would only make that change if they figure the new implementation works better for most use cases. `mutableListOf` would then have you using that new list implementation transparently, and you'd get that better behaviour for free. Go with `mutableListOf` if that sounds like your case.

On the other hand, maybe you spent a bunch of time thinking about your problem, and figured that `ArrayList` *really* is the best fit for your problem, and you don't want to risk getting moved to something sub-optimal. Then you probably want to either use `ArrayList` directly, or use the `arrayListOf` factory function (an `ArrayList`-specific analogue to `mutableListOf`).

Answer (score 34):

[`mutableListOf<T>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html) is an inline function invocation that returns a 
 [`MutableList<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/). As of today, `mutableListOf` does return an instance of `ArrayList`.

[`ArrayList<String>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/) is a constructor invocation and cannot be inlined.

In other words, given:

```
 val a = mutableListOf<String>()
 val b = ArrayList<String>()
```

- `a` is of type `MutableList<String>`
- `b` is of type `ArrayList<String>`

At runtime, both `a` and `b` will hold an instance of [`ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/).

Note that inlining is particularly useful when combined with [type reification](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), which justifies the existence of `listOf`, `mutableListOf` and the like.

Comment: So there is no difference.

Comment: `a` and `b` have different declared type - so there's a difference at compile time.

Comment: It can be inlined as `val b = arrayListOf<String>()`

Answer (score 15):

Under the covers, both mutableListOf() and arrayListOf() create an instance of ArrayList. ArrayList is a class that happens to implement the MutableList interface.

The only difference is that arrayListOf() returns the ArrayList as an actual ArrayList. mutableListOf() returns a MutableList, so the actual ArrayList is "disguised" as just the parts that are described by the MutableList interface.

The difference, in practice, is that ArrayList has a few methods that are not part of the MutableList interface (trimToSize and ensureCapacity).

The difference, philosophically, is that the MutableList only cares about the behaviour of the object being returned. It just returns "something that acts like a MutableList". The ArrayList cares about the "structure" of the object. It allows you to directly manipulate the memory allocated by the object (trimToSize).

The rule of thumb is that you should prefer the interface version of things (mutableListOf()) unless you actually have a reason to care about the exact details of the underlying structure.

Or, in other words, if you don't know which one you want, choose mutableListOf first.

Answer (score 12):

As you can see in [sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L96):

```
public inline fun <T> mutableListOf(): MutableList<T> = ArrayList()
```

So, there is no difference, just a convenience method.

Comment: And I would put "convenience" in quotes.  Until MutableList *actually* has a different implementation, providing a core object that does the same thing as another core object is confusing, and not at all a convenience.  :(

Comment: @MikeWilliamson since array-list is one of the most confusing things is Java, to me it's either an array or a list but both? My head explodes. I find the mutable-list is a perfect name for the weirdly named type.