# Convert an ArrayMap to ArrayList - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have an ArrayMap and I want a list of Chat to create and recyclerview.

```
val chats : ArrayMap<String,Chat>? = ArrayMap()
```

RecyclerView.Adapter

```
class ChatAdapter(var chats : ArrayList<Chat>){
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I get this ArrayMap from firebase. What is the best way to get an ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use ArrayList in the public constructor (because then you make youself depending on exactly that implementation). Should be the `MutableList` interface:

```
class ChatAdapter(var chats : MutableList<Chat>){
```

I guess the `ArrayMap` is a usual `Map` (because I don't know that class).
You can just write

```
val chats : ArrayMap<String,Chat>? = ArrayMap()
// ... initialize the chat
val adapter = ChatAdapter(am.values.toMutableList())
```

If you really need the `ArrayList` class for some reason, you can write

```
val adapter = ChatAdapter(ArrayList(am.values))
```

Comment: I can't understande this "You shouldn't use ArrayList in the public constructor (because then you make youself depending on exactly that implementation).", but your second solution works: val adapter = ChatAdapter(ArrayList(am.values))

Comment: I found this other solution:
ChatAdapter(user.chats.map { it.value } as ArrayList<Chat>)

Comment: ArrayList is an implementation, MutableList an interface. If possible, always use the interface e.g. in your case use the interface in the constructor. Because then you can pass ANY implementation (as ArrayList) to your ChatAdapter. Else you can just pass an ArrayList.

Comment: I wouldn't use user.chats.map { it.value } as ArrayList<Chat> because this has much more runtime overhead than ArrayList(am.values)

Comment: I changed it to your second solution.
I found this post about what you say: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43116238/1593067
Is that your point?

Comment: Yes, this describes it quite well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148188/discussion-between-guenhter-and-beto-caldas).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an ArrayList explicitly, you can use the `ArrayMap.map()` function like this:

```
val chats : ArrayMap<String,Chat>? = ArrayMap()
val list : List<Chat> = chats.map { it.value }
```

Comment: I commented about this on checked solution.

Comment: Thanks. I already thought it might be more expensive at runtime but wasn't sure so i thought it might not hurt to see another possible way. At least it's not completely wrong i guess.