# How to create list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I tried these in Kotlin REPL

```
var listA = listOf(null ,null)
var listB = [null, null]
```

The first line works fine as expected. On displaying listA I get:

```
[null, null]
```

The second line throws the following error:

```
error: cannot use 'Nothing?' as reified type parameter
var listB = [null,null]
            ^
error: unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]
var listB = [null,null]
            ^
error: unsupported [Array<Nothing> in return type is illegal]
var listB = [null,null]
            ^
```

When I try the same with non null types,
i.e.

```
var listC = [1,2]
```

I get this error:

```
error: unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]
var listC = [1,2]
            ^
```

I'm new to Kotlin. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the Kotlin [documentation on Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html):

> Kotlin does not have dedicated syntax constructs for creating lists or sets. Use methods from the standard library, such as listOf(), mutableListOf(), setOf(), mutableSetOf().

There are no list literals [currently](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-language-feature-requests/1001/5) for code outside of annotations.

Answer (score 44):

As [@Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50318950/7380430) pointed out, there is not syntax for `[null, null]`.
However, Kotlin does have some handy methods for handling lists and arrays.

### Lists

- listOf()

  > Creates a new read-only List.
- listOfNotNull()

  > Basically the same as listOf(), but without null values. Even empty strings 
  >   are skipped.
- arrayListOf()

  > Creates an ArrayList. This time you can modify (add/remove) elements.
- mutableListOf()

  > Behaves like arrayListOf(). Actually, mutableListOf() internally uses ArrayLists. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114367/difference-between-arrayliststring-and-mutablelistofstring-in-kotlin/)

### Arrays

- arrayOf()

  > This creates an array, which is very different to most languages you know.
  >   Instead of syntax structures like {1, 2, 3} or [1, 2, 3] you have functions 
  >   in Kotlin. You also get functions for typed array:
  >
  > - booleanArrayOf()
  > - doubleArrayOf()
  > - charArrayOf()
  > - ...

One exception are annotations, which explains your compiler error `[Collection literals outside of annotations]`:

```
@MyAnnotation(arguments = [1, 2, 3])
```

However, this could change in the future as discussed [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-language-feature-requests/1001).

---

While working with arrays, it is important to know the return types those functions are creating. 
As an example:
`Array<Int>` is an `Integer[]` under the hood, while `IntArray` is a primitive `int[]` when targeting the JVM.

Answer (score 12):

So for the case of mutable lists, you can declare an empty `String` one with: `val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()`. If you wanted an immutable list then you could use `val` like so: `val list: List<String> = listOf("x", "y", "z")`.

Also note, that you should consider your use case for using `val` or `var`. Mutability of a list pertains to values within the list itself, where as `val` and `var` are for the variable. You can reassign the list if you use `var` but not `val` (similar to final of Java)

For the sake of clarity, as an example, mutable lists can have elements added an removed after their initialisation, while immutable cannot.

[Immutable Lists Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html)

[Mutable List Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html)

Comment: Isn't val similar to final and not mutable, but var is?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re Yeah you are right with respect to val vs var, I updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You get `[null, null]` because [that's how `toString()` happens to be defined in `java.util.AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29) and `listOf` creates a `java.util.ArrayList` which inherits this implementation.

The errors you get are because there *is* a place in Kotlin where this syntax happens to work: [annotation parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations). So the parser understands it. But it creates arrays, not lists, and so your code wouldn't compile even if the syntax wasn't limited to annotations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is not the correct syntax for creating `List` with Kotlin.
Here is an example of `List` and `MutableList`(with write operations) and some of the operations you can do on them:

List

```
val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four")
println("Number of elements: ${numbers.size}")
println("Third element: ${numbers.get(2)}")
println("Fourth element: ${numbers[3]}")
println("Index of element \"two\" ${numbers.indexOf("two")}")
```

MutableList

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
numbers.add(5)
numbers.removeAt(1)
numbers[0] = 0
numbers.shuffle()
println(numbers)
```