# RemoveAt not found in list kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a list whose value is filled from API

```
var dataList: List<Data?>? = null
```

I need to remove the element from 0th index

while in java I could use

```
dataList.removeAt(0)
```

But I don't see the function in kotlin

Comment: can you please show us some data in your list? and how you fill the list

Comment: same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913252/kotlins-list-missing-add-remove-map-missing-put-etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/#list) supports only read-only access while [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) supports adding and removing elements.

so `var dataList: MutableList<Data?>? = null` 
will give you the option to remove an element.

Answer (score 2):

This is because unlike java `List` is immutable in Kotlin. That means you can't modify after declaring it. To get functionalities like add,remove you can declare a mutable list in Kotlin like this:

```kotlin
val mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()
mutableList.add("Some data")
mutableList.removeAt(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove an item from a [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/).  Nor can you add an item, nor change one.  That's because `List` is a read-only interface!

If the list is mutable, you could instead have a [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) reference to it.  `MutableList` is a subinterface that adds all the methods for adding, changing, and removing items.