# Kotlin: exposing immutable list in API

Tags: collections, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and am wrestling with the problem of returning immutable versions of internally mutable lists.

I reviewed the following '[Kotlin: Modifying (immutable) List through cast, is it legitimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956425/kotlin-modifying-immutable-list-through-cast-is-it-legitimate)' and understand that immutable lists are really just read-only views which do not expose the modification methods.

I want to have a class which exposes an "immutable" List and still want to take advantage of Kotlins automatic getters (without having to provide all the boilerplate for getting the list or a member of the list)

Is the following a bad idea (or will it cause a problem that may be blocked in future releases)

```
class Foo {
  val names: List<String> = LinkedList;

  fun addName(name: String) {
    (names as LinkedList).add(name)
  }
}
```

I am looking to allow (for example):

```
  val foo = Foo;
  println(foo.names.size)
```

But still prevent the caller from modifying the internals of the class (at least as much as possible). For example removing elements or clearing the backing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```
class Foo {
    private val _names: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    val names: List<String>
        get() = _names.toList()

    fun addName(name: String) {
        _names.add(name)
    }
}
```

The toList means that if they cast it to a `MutableList<String>` and try to add to it they will get an `UnsupportedOperationException`, the `_names` field holds the real data, and external access is done via the names property

Comment: Thanks jrtapsell,

Yes I know I can maintain this second variable as well... but that wasn't sure if needed the additional clutter.. 

I think it also works like this:

`val name: List<String> = _names`

Comment: ... although that probably would not prevent the cast

Comment: The names property just acts as a immutable view of _names, although it would be nice if the clutter could be reduced

Comment: Using the backing field may simplify the code: [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Define mutable list as a private property with underscore (a kind of "field" in Kotlin) and expose it through another public read-only property.

If the "field" is read-only this will do the trick 
(suggested by @JWT):

```
class Foo {
    private val _names: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    val names: List<String> = _names

    fun addName(name: String) {
        _names.add(name)
    }
}
```

If the "field" might be reassigned, it will require to define getter as a function (note `var _names`):

```
class Foo2 {
    private var _names: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    val names: List<String>
        get() = _names

    fun addName(name: String) {
        _names.add(name)
    }

    fun reset() {
        _names = mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

Tests are available [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/d269t0nhbo9u661mr4mdtv30g1/5rraf5rad7hpjbvsnbg3r372e9).