# Does Kotlin provide any implementations of its collection interfaces?

Tags: java, c#, kotlin

I see that Kotlin provides a number of interfaces for implementing collections. They are listed on [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html).

I do not see any implementations of these provided by Kotlin.

I do, however, see that there are functions in the global namespace that help us create instances of these collections. For e.g. to create a mutable list of numbers, we may say:

```
var numbers : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3);
```

To create a read-only view of the list, we may say:

```
val readOnlyViewOfNumbers : List<Int> = numbers;
```

Or, to create a read-only list of numbers, we may say:

```
val readOnlyListOfNumbers : List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3);
```

To create a list of `n` items and initialize each element with the value `null`, we might say:

```
// Sorry, I forgot the function name for this one. It
// is not nullableListOf(...)
val numbers : List<Int> = nullableListOf(n);
```

To create an Array, say, 5 elements with an initializer function for each element of the array, we may say:

```
val myArray : Array<Int> = Array(5, (i) => { /* return whatever */ };
```

However, if I'd like to create a `List<Book>` without any books in it but I'd simply like to initialize it like this (Java or C# code):

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); // Java or
List<Book> books = new List<Book>(); // C#
```

How may I do that in Kotlin?

Are there publicly exposed implementations of its collection interfaces? Do they have default constructors?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727657/kotlin-and-immutable-collections/38002121 for thorough overview of Kotlin and collections

Comment: Take a look at this repo https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable

Comment: @IRus Sorry, am I missing something? Those are a bunch of interfaces. Where's the implementation?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 inside git submodule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin uses the implementations of Java.

So

```
val list = listOf<T>()
```

is basically

```
val list: List<T> = ArrayList<T>()
```

These functions are created for convenience

Using Java-Collections is fine too:

```
val list: List<Book> = ArrayList<Book>()
val mutableList: MutableList<Book> = ArrayList<Book>()
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand that I can use the Java collections. I was under the impression that Kotlin standard library provided its own implementations as well.

Comment: They reused as much as possible of java to have a small standard-library (benefits on android -> dex-count) and to maximize interoperability.