# How to use immutable persistent collections in Kotlin?

Tags: collections, kotlin, immutability

I want to use immutable persistent collections, like the ones Clojure uses, in Kotlin. Which libraries can I use (both in the JVM and in Javascript)? How well they integrate with Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

As answered in this [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34476880/8073652), there are several Java libraries you can easily use in Kotlin:

- Guava (https://github.com/google/guava)
- Dexx (https://github.com/andrewoma/dexx)
- Eclipse Collections (formerly GS-Collections, https://www.eclipse.org/collections/)
- PCollections (http://pcollections.org/)

The most interesting thing: Kotlin has its own solution, which can be found here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable (based on *PCollections*).

Comment: What about Javascript? Which of these libraries can compile to Javascript?

Comment: The Kotlin official solution, as found in the github repo

Comment: I didn't get it. What is the "official solution"? Can you share a link to it?