# Resizeable two-dimensional array in Kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, list, kotlin, arraylist

**I want to know how to make a resizeable two-dimensional array in Kotlin.**

C++ example: `vector< vector<int> > my_vector`

What I've tried: `var seqList: List<List<Int>> = ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>>()`

but I'm getting an error when using seqList.add()

> error: unresolved reference: add

I have read some questions regarding 2d arrays in Kotlin at stackoverflow, but they are about not-resizeable arrays or are outdated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin has separate [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) and [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) interfaces, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732403/4465208), for example. `ArrayList` is a `MutableList`, you just have to save it as a `MutableList` variable in order to be able to access methods that mutate it:

```
val seqList: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = ArrayList() // alternatively: = mutableListOf()

seqList.add(mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3))
```

Also note the [`mutableListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html) and [`arrayListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html) methods in the standard library, which are handy for creating lists instead of directly using the constructor of, say, `ArrayList`.

Comment: I've pasted your code and run it, but I'm getting "Error:(6, 50) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>> but MutableList<MutableList<Int>> was expected"

Comment: Since `MutableList<T>` is in variant on `T`, `MutableList<ArrayList<Int>>` is not assignable to `MutableList<MutableList<Int>>`, neither is `ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>>`. Instead, use `ArrayList<MutableList<Int>>()` on the right hand side, or omit the type argument to make the compiler infer it: just `ArrayList()`

Comment: Oops, my bad, should've tried running the code. You can do what @hotkey suggested, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that there's another function in the standard library since Kotlin 1.1 which might be useful here: the factory function [`MutableList(n) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html)